# PHP create 3D Array from Array with 3 Values

Tags: php, arrays, transform

again me:

following array;

```
$myArray = array('FOO', 'BAR', 'HELLO');
```

i need:

```
$myArray['FOO']['BAR']['HELLO'] = 0;
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
 function onion($a) {
  return $a ? array(array_shift($a) => onion($a)) : 0;
}

$myArray = array('FOO', 'BAR', 'HELLO');
print_r(onion($myArray));
```

//edit: actually [doc's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722632/php-create-3d-array-from-array-with-3-values/1722778#1722778) is better, his/her code, a bit improved

```
  $new = 0;
  foreach (array_reverse($myArray) as $v)
       $new = array($v => $new);
```

Comment: very nice, this is much cleaner than the implementation I wrote. ArneRie really sould accept this as being correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
$newarr[array_pop($myarr)] = 0;
foreach (array_reverse($myarr) as $v)
    $newarr[$v] = $newarr;
```

Comment: Every recursive algorithm has non-recursive equivalent ;)

Answer (score 1):

You might try `$newArray[$myArray[0]][$myArray[1]][$myArray[2]] = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

```
$newArray = array($oldArray[0] => array($oldArray[1] => array($oldArray[2] => 0)));
```

Comment: sure but i need to create it "automatic" i dont know how many keys or values in my source.. (-:

Answer (score 1):

you could do it with recursion:

```
function arrToKeys(&$arr,$initialCount){
   if($initialCount == 0 ){
      return $arr;
   }
   else{
      $newKey = $arr[0];
      unset($arr[0]);
      $arr[$newKey] = $arr;
      $initialCount--;
      return arrToKeys($arr,$initialCount);  
   }
}

//then call it like this
$newArr = arrToKeys($myArray,count($myArray));
```

Comment: That function throws a segmentation fault. And you're missing a closing bracket